# What method to use to turn a pandas dataframe from wide to long?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataset that i am using is the following dataset: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwgg/Airports/master/airports.json

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwgg/Airports/master/airports.json'

r = requests.get(url)

json_data = r.json()

data = pd.DataFrame(json_data)
```

This is a dataset that has 28868 columns and 10 rows and the essence of my question is what method do I need to use to flip the dataframe so it has 10 columns and 28868 rows?

The function melt turns the dataframe but not in an useful manner, for example:

```
data = data.reset_index()
pd.melt(data, id_vars="index", value_vars=['00AK', '00AL', '00AZ','00CA','00CO'])
```

Comment: did you try `data.T`

Comment: You can simply transpose the dataframe - df.transpose(inplace=True) ?

Comment: No, I did not as I was not aware that existed. Thank you